# TypeScript array filter only RegExp

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to filter only `RegExp` expressions and get an error.

```
const arr = ['test', '/test/', /test/, /test/g]; 
const regs: RegExp[] = arr.filter(str => str instanceof RegExp);
```

```
Type '(string | RegExp)[]' is not assignable to type 'RegExp[]'.
  Type 'string | RegExp' is not assignable to type 'RegExp'.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'RegExp'.
```

[example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gcigU2pgGhkwHpdoTCYy8oSiaKBzAXQG4AoUSWBHJiAC4YAJX4BRAB4AHdC1TwkAOgBmASwA2uBAApoyFAD4Y+mGp5wwwHCBWiJMgJRsgA)

How can I avoid such an error by getting only a list of `RegExp` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to tell typescript that provided callback is a type guard:

```
const regs: RegExp[] = arr.filter((str): str is RegExp => str instanceof RegExp);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gcigU2pgGhkwHpdoTCYy8oSiaKBzAXQG4AoUSWBHJiAC4YAJX4BRAB4AHdC1TwkAOgBmASwA2uBAAod0BAEphBmGoiiJM1AD4YptTzhhgOECstMp0w2yA)

---

Then you can also remove explicit variable typing:

```
const regs = arr.filter((str): str is RegExp => str instanceof RegExp);
```

Comment: Unbelievable, thanks, where can I learn more about this?

Comment: Here's the documentation on type guards https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates Also look at linked question for more details